# Using declarative features, is it possible to update an Event, if available, on a Case

Tags: administration, process-automation

I have an installation date field on a Case. Whenever this installation date field is entered(this can be at the time of or can be at a later point of case creation), I am creating a calendar event whose dates are calculated based on the installation dates.

Now, if someone updates the installation date field on the case, we want its related event to be updated with the new dates/times. There will be only one event per "Installation Date" change on a case. It means, there can be multiple events on a case, but there will always be only one event that deals with "Installation Date" change.

These are the design questions I am having problems with, What is the best way to relate Case and Event based on installation date and not just through a WhatId? Is there any way to achieve this whole thing declaratively?

Comment: why would you not use WhatId?

Comment: I will have to use WhatId. I will also have to use/create a field to say that this event is related to a Case that is "installation date" related.

Comment: you could use Event recordtypes rather than create a special field

Comment: You could do this with a Record Triggered Flow completely declaratively.

Comment: @sfdcfox you legend. Thank you.